# Initialization of only few values of c# array?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, initialization

I am trying to write a program in which, I want to initialize 4 starting values of an array, while the other 16 will be entered manually from the console.

For this I have written the following code:

```
int[] intArray = new int[20] { 20, 22, 23, 0 };
```

But I am getting the following exception: **"An array initializer of '20' is expected"**

I know that it can be done by this syntax :

```
int[] intArray = new int[20];
intArray[0] = 20;
intArray[1] = 22;
intArray[2] = 23;
intArray[3] = 0;
```

I would like to know if this can be achieved in one line.

Comment: "but i wanna know any how can i do this in one line" - why do you need to? Basically there's no particularly simple way of doing this. There are various ways you *could* do it with LINQ, but nothing desperately simple. `new[] { 20, 22, 23, 0 }.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(0, 16)).ToArray()` would do it, for example...

Comment: I assume by *one line* you mean one statement? Because you could do `int[] intArray = new int[20]; intArray[0] = 20; intArray[1] = 22; intArray[2] = 23; intArray[3] = 0; ` as one line, but it is the same number of statements...

Comment: yes its working but will you please enplane me how? its working @ jon Skeet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to be needing this frequently, you could create your own extension method to populate the values in an existing array:

```
int[] intArray = new int[20].Populate(20, 22, 23, 0);
```

Sample implementation:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static TList Populate<TList, TElement>(this TList list, params TElement[] values)
        where TList : IList<TElement>
    {
        // TODO: argument validation

        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            list[i] = values[i];

        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes its one of the best and  correct way, but i am looking for something as suggested by @jon skeet.

Answer (score 1):

How about keeping it simple:

```
public static T[] CreateAndInitArray<T>( int len, T[] initialValues )
{
    var temp = new T[len];
    initialValues.CopyTo( temp, 0 );
    return temp;
}
```

Use:

```
int[] intArray = CreateAndInitArray( 20, new int[] { 20, 22, 23, 0 } );
```

The `initialValues` argument could be a `params` argument too, but that would easily be confusing considering the length argument. Personally I like the answer Douglas provided better, looks alot more logical.

Comment: yes it's a right way to do the thing i want +1 @chris

Answer (score 0):

This works in two lines:

```
  int[] intArray = new int[20];
  new int[4] { 20, 22, 23, 0 }.CopyTo(intArray , 0);
```

Or even:

```
  int[] intArray = new int[20];
  new int[] { 20, 22, 23, 0 }.CopyTo(intArray , 0);
```

Note that the unnamed array goes out of scope right after the semicolon.. - I don't think it gets any simpler!

Answer (score 0):

I found jon skeet suggestion more useful.

```
new[] { 20, 22, 23, 0 }.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(0, 16)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that you could do something like this:

```
    private static int[] getInput()
    {

        int[] array = { 20, 22, 23, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,    1, 1 };

        bool done = false;
        int current = 4;
        while (!done)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter in a number to be added to the array");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            array[current] = Convert.ToInt32(input);
            current++;
            if (current==array.Length)
            {
                done = true;
            }
        }
        return array;
    }
```